# Installing an old version of Node.js on a Vagrant VM

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-12.04

I'm setting up a Vagrant environment for a client with some legacy dependencies that require Node.js v0.4.12. I know I can install it via nvm, but that's provisioning the box with NVM and starting the node app is proving...problematic. In a perfect world, I'd be able to install old versions via `apt` (`apt-get install nodejs=0.4.12`), but that doesn't seem to be an option. I can't find a single PPA that retains old versions.

I know I can pull and compile from source (that's where I'll go if I have to), but I'm wondering whether there are any other options I just haven't found. I also need `npm`.

Comment: They don't have versions back to v0.4, but you might look at http://www.nodejs.org/dist/ to see if a different version you can use is available.

Comment: Versions -- even 0.4 -- that I can compile definitely exist (I looked at `/dist` right before I posted here), but thought I'd at least ask if there was an easier way before I went old school. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever it's worth, I ended up installing with [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). There are still some minor issues to resolve like existing the provision script cleanly, but Node gets installed and started successfully so I guess that's the answer. At least for now.